# Is it possible to use a Mac as Build Server and as Desktop PC in parallel?

Tags: mac, xcode

I have an iMac. I want to use it as my personal mac in my company. But I have also colleagues who want to use the iMac for building via Xcode. Is this possible? My use cases are:

- Im not logged in --> Xcode building should be possible
- Im logged in with my user --> Xcode building should be possible

The idea is, that i don´t need a separate Mac for only building apps.

Comment: Assuming these other people aren't on Mac, then you'd need to look into some kind of VNC solution to log into a backgrounded account that they can build on. This will slow your machine to a crawl while they're doing it, btw. I'm sure you'd be better off setting up a Mac Mini to do this.

Comment: Doesn't XCode have a full set of command-line tools for building?  So, if they don't need the XCode UI, they can SSH into the iMac and run the commands.  If you really don't want them doing it when you're logged in, you'll either need to turn off SSH access when you login (and remember to turn it on before you log out), or create some shell scripts/agents/daemons that do it for you, or update their build scripts to check for logged on users before proceeding.

Comment: I tried now to add a new user and use vnc for screensharing. The performance of the screensharing is terrible. So that is no suitable solution.

Comment: "performance " how? You're not really adding much detail that anyone could actually work with. I doubt you'll ever get much performance out of what you want. It would be considerably faster for people to build on their own machines. If you still want some performance in reserve, then set up an identical VM using Parallels & build in that. Seth the VM to use the physical core count of the machine it's on, then the user & the VM will split their needs via HT, keeping both running reasonably well. If you really want a build farm, then you need Mac Pros, not iMacs.